# Salesforce Server time out

Tags: soql, developer-console

I am running following SOQL and "sometimes" getting server timeout error.

```
SELECT Id, BccAddress, ParentId, CcAddress, CreatedById, CreatedDate, IsDeleted, ReplyToEmailMessageId, FromAddress, FromName, 
       HasAttachment, Headers, HtmlBody, Incoming, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MessageDate, Status, Subject, SystemModstamp, TextBody, ToAddress, ActivityId 
    FROM EmailMessage 
    WHERE LASTMODIFIEDDATE  < LAST_N_DAYS:90 limit 100
```

Worry is why sometimes it works fine and sometimes it returns server time-out error straight away.

Comment: Is this the only query in your class? If not then share your code.

Comment: @krishsfdc Firstly I am having timeout problem even if I am running this query in developer console. Secondly I am using REST based api call for this query.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't see any field which is not required other than isDeleted and removing that does not solve this. 

I think problem is with where clause and more specifically "LAST_N_DAYS"

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think he mean all the fields are of interest for him except isDeleted.